# How do you get an amount for different locations?

Tags: sql, select, sum

I'm trying to get a different amount for different locations. Here's my query.

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount) AS amount, amount (SELECT amount WHERE @location = loc1) loc_amount
```

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: What sort of sql is that? Where's your from clause??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: I think you are trying to mean [GROUP BY statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to sum up your query? If that's so it would be something like `SELECT SUM(a.amount) As amount, loc FROM table a GROUP BY loc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
select Sum(s.amount) as TotalAmount From SomeTable s
inner join Select sum(l.amount) as LocationAmount From SomeTable l where l.loc1 = @location
```

would be one way to it